# how do I move a pem file which is downloaded to Windows 10 and move it to root@Ubuntu?

Tags: 12.04

There is a pem key from AWS that is downloaded to my Windows 10.
The Jenkins and Nginx is installed using Ubuntu 20.04 LTS (WSL2) at Root.

Now, in order for all to work together, I need to bring this pem key which is in Windows 10 to Ubuntu Root.  How do I make that happen?

Alternatively, I "could" regenerate a pem key from AWS and make it saved in Ubuntu or downloaded to Ubuntu instead of Windows 10.  How to make that happen?

Comment: You mention 20.04 is your question, but have tagged your release as being 12.04/precise - why?  Please clarify which you're on & how the two releases relate?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are using WSL ?

You can access your windows files under this directory

```
cd /mnt/c/Users/<ubuntu.username>/Downloads
```

Then you can copy it to your directory and then change permissions

Comment: i did what you say root@DESKTOP-SB41UI7:~# cd /mnt/c/Users/<ubuntu.root>/Downloads
-bash: ubuntu.root: No such file or directory

Answer (score 0):

Your drive can be accessed from the `/mnt/` directory in WSL.
With that said if you can simply navigate to `/mnt/c/Users/{windows.user}/Downloads/` - replacing `{windows.user}` with your exact windows username, you'll be able to see all downloads that have been downloaded in windows.
Think of the directory of `/mnt/c` as a shortcut to the `C:` drive directory.

So in order to copy a file from windows to say the home directory of the current WSL user, you can use either the `cp` (copy) or the `mv` (move) commands like so:

```bsh
# say the windows user name is Saleem for this example
$ cp /mnt/c/Users/Saleem/Downloads/aws.pem ~/aws.pem

# to move a file (cut/paste)
$ mv /mnt/c/Users/Saleem/Downloads/aws.pem ~/aws.pem
```

The syntax for `cp` is `cp [options] SOURCE DEST`,
and for `mv` is `mv [options] SOURCE DEST`

> the `[options]` argument is optional.
> as long as you are dealing with files its the same syntax, but for directories, you'd pass `-R` or `-r` (recurse through directories) option to `cp`, while `mv` just works for both files and directories without any extra options.

To learn more about usage of linux commands use `man {command}`, this will display the *man pages* of the command in question, which is a documentation for usage/features for the command.

Comment: It doesn't work.  Here's what I did : https://pastebin.com/9EAY9KZn

Comment: Your syntax is incorrect its `cp SOURCE DEST` there is no `//` after cp , if the folder path has spaces surround the path with `"`

Comment: Why is there a `/to/` ?

Comment: `cp` **space** `"/mnt/c/Users/karen/Udacity And SUSE Cloud Native/AWS-Jenkin-Practice/jenkins-master.pem.txt/to/Users/root/jenkins-master.pem"` **space** `~/ssh/jenkins-master.pem.txt` --> assuming master.pem.txt is a folder

Comment: hi @SaleemKhair, how do i create a folder ssh  jenkins-master is a pem file but I do not know why when I use locate pem it indicate a .txt behind